# I can not save my data in sqlite in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an app and I want to save something in sqlite database.
My project name is `Hesabdari`.
I copy my database in :
`Hesabdari\app\build\intermediates\assets\databases\hesabdari.sqlite.`

I have a MyDatabase class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hesabdari.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    setForcedUpgrade();

}}
```

I have Earning class like shown below:

```
public class Earning extends AppCompatActivity {

OnClickListener listenPlease = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Earning.this , EarningForm.class);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }

};


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_earning);
    Button record_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
        record_btn.setOnClickListener(listenPlease);
}}
```

I have EarningForm class like shown below :

```
public class EarningForm extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyDatabase MyDatabase;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_earning_form);
    Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTaeed);
    save.setOnClickListener(listentodb);
    MyDatabase = new MyDatabase(this);
    mydb = MyDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
     }
    View.OnClickListener listentodb = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("mablagh", R.id.txtMablagh);
        values.put("daste", R.id.btnDaste);
        values.put("hasab", R.id.spinner1);
        values.put("tarikh", R.id.etxTarikh);
        values.put("tozih", R.id.etxTozihat);
       //            mydb.insert("daramad", null, values);
       //            mydb.close();
    }

};
```

In my program, when I click on `btnRecord` I got the below error:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.monire.hesabdari/com.example.monire.hesabdari.EarningForm}: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/hesabdari.sqlite file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable"
```

I understand that this error is because of the below line:

```
 mydb = MyDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
```

What can I do to solve this issue ?

Comment: did you set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Your DB is in `Hesabdari\app\build\intermediates\assets\databases\hesabdari.sqlite`. Copy it to `/data/data/com.example.monire.hesabdari/databases` then use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right path. To acces your device database folder, click on Tools -> Android -> Android device monitor. Then click on your device, take the File Explorer tab and then data -> data -> your.application.name -> database